# CPU usage investigation and managing daemons

Tags: daemon

I am not sure, if this question belongs here or to software recommendation, but as it is strictly tied to linux kernel and is probably build-in, so I will risk and ask here (please move it if I am mistaken).

I understand, that I can manage currently running daemons with sudo service (...) and I can permanently enable/disable them by re/moving them in /etc/init.d.
However, this is all done from terminal and must be done with root privileges.

Is there some application with gui and checkboxes, that allows easily enable/disable daemons that runs currently as well as on start up?

I am asking mostly because I see constant 25% (one core) cpu usage, but xfce-taskmanager run with root doesn't really show any process that consumes more than 3%.
Xubuntu 16.04, am I infected or something?

Comment: What the top command shows?

Comment: Oh, how could I forget about top! it indeed shows, that autokey uses that much cpu... interesting. I have killed it and restarted and now works fine. Why I couldn't see it in xfce-taskmanager? What about daemon manager?

Comment: I know its strange but my instincts is simple preventing me for installing anything related, because of the colors. Do you are ordering by the CPU? Try to run the tool as root and see if there is some difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand (I am not English native speaker). I was running xfce-taskmanager as root and it didn't display process that took whole cpu core.